# How to implement multiple Google Cloud Functions with Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, serverless

I would like to implement Google Cloud Functions with Cloud SQL. What is the best way to implement Google Cloud Functions with Cloud SQL?.

I am able to connect to MySQL and execute query. But I am unable to share the connection with other function.

> Do we need to create a new connection for each function or can we share the same MySQL connection with all functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to force all function invocations to share the same connection.  That's because Cloud Functions runs potentially many server instances to handle all the invocations.  None of these instances share memory or other resources with each other.

However, you can optimize your code to share a connection between invocations of a function that happen to occur on the same server instance, before it's shut down.  If you store objects in a global scope, they can be reused between invocations.